# Magento 2 - Display subcategories above product listing

Tags: magento2, module, category, layout, template

I'm trying to display the first 8 subcategories above the product listing on a select few category pages.

I know that I can easily do this using static blocks, but I'd rather use a custom template to do this.

I don't really need help with the PHP code to fetch the subcategories, I'm just not sure about the exact structure in magento 2 to use.

I know I need a custom `.phtml` template at least, but I'm not sure where to place the PHP methods to use in my template as I've never developed a custom module.

Also, I'm assuming that for each category that I'd want the subcategories to display on, I can use update the layout in the admin on the category's "custom design" tab.

Comment: You need to display custom block in category page.

Comment: My module has this function https://github.com/magepow/magento2-categories follow this to solve your problem.